# Query multiple OSM node keys in R

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I have a big table that contains a set of osm_nodes_keys, like the following working example:

```
 a <- c(5993651, 27886377, 104537102)
 b <- c("a", "b", "c")
 df <- data.frame(osm_nodes_keys = a, myid= b)
```

I would like to be able to make a map in R, starting from the osm_nodes_keys column. How do I do a batch geocode?

Comment: What's going on with `b <- c(a,b,c)`? We don't know what `b` and `c` are on the right hand side. This code doesn't work as writ.

Comment: I added the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `osmdata` package you can query OSM by id:

```
> a <- c(5993651, 27886377, 104537102)
> nodes = osmdata_sf(opq_string(opq_osm_id(id=a, type="node")))
> ways = osmdata_sf(opq_string(opq_osm_id(id=a, type="way")))
> relations = osmdata_sf(opq_string(opq_osm_id(id=a, type="relation")))

> plot(relations$osm_multipolygons$geometry)
```

[image]

that's a forest:

```
> relations$osm_multipolygons
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 18.48087 ymin: 46.82215 xmax: 18.49941 ymax: 46.82766
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
        landuse         type                       geometry
5993651  forest multipolygon MULTIPOLYGON (((18.4822 46....
```

its possible for ways and relations to have the same OSM id so you need to know what you're querying for.